# Unable to access jar file for EurekaClient

Tags: spring, shell, jar, netflix-eureka

I am trying to run this command from my jar file.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=abc-service-replica01 SpringCloudDiscoveryEurekaClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am getting this error

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile SpringCloudDiscoveryEurekaClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have changed permission by chmod but it still doesn't work.

Comment: which error? There is no error in your question.

Comment: I mistyped my question. Sorry.